# Integral involving the CDF of a normal and a nonlinear function

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, normal-distribution, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

I know that the following result holds

Given $a,b,\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$,  $\Phi$ the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random variable, and $f_X$ the probability density function of a normal random variable $X\sim {N}(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$
\begin{equation}
    \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(\lambda x\right)\Phi\left(ax + b\right) f_X(x) d x = \exp\left( \mu_X \lambda+ \frac{\sigma_X^2\lambda^2}{2}\right) \Phi\left(  \frac{a\left(\mu_X+\sigma_X^2\lambda\right)+b}{\sqrt{1+a^2\sigma_X^2}}\right) 
\end{equation}

However, I was wondering if, by any chance, something can be said about a more general integral, i.e.
\begin{equation}
    \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(\lambda x\right)\Phi\left(g(x)\right) f_X(x) d x  
\end{equation}
with $g$ a mononote function.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I believe there is no closed form solution unless $g$ is a linear function (in that case, the closed form solution comes from the fact that a linear sum of 2 normal random variables is also a normal random variable).

Comment: I thought the same. Thank you for looking into it anyway